# ARES track mode pcb

Tags: pcb-design, proteus

I'm beginner in ARES and want to know what does the T in track mode mean?
and the unit th means ?

[image: track mode]

[image: th scale]

Comment: "wanna" is not english!

Comment: The width of the track in Mil ( thou) equivalent to 1/1000 of an inch, that is 0.001 inches

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the T is thou. So T20 is 20 thou. The unit th is also meaning thou. It is also called Mil, which should not be confused with millimetre! A thou is equal to 1/1000 of an inch or 0.001 inches as pointed out by G36 in the comments.

Comment: Mil is usually used by (non-metric) electrical engineers and Thou by (non-metric) mechanical engineers. If you go metric you only need to worry about mm and microns.

Comment: True. But it can get confusing the first time you hear mil if you are used to it being used to talk about millimetres. Happened to me first time, hence why I mentioned it